# addWMSTiles don't render

Tags: r, leaflet

I am trying to use a specific tile service in R leaflet via `addWMSTiles` (EQ risk in Germany).

However, it's not working as nothing is rendered.

Here is the code:

```
library(leaflet)

map <- leaflet()   %>%
  addProviderTiles(providers$Stamen.TonerLite,group="StamenTonerLite")

wmsserv <- "https://www.gisimmorisknaturgefahren.de/erdbeben_tile"
map <- addWMSTiles(map, wmsserv, layers="erdbeben_tile", options=WMSTileOptions(Format="image/png", TRANSPARENT=TRUE, CRS="EPSG:25832", opacity=0.6))
```

Here is the [link](https://www.gisimmorisknaturgefahren.de/erdbeben_tile?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=true&CRS=EPSG%3A25832&STYLES=&WIDTH=2741&HEIGHT=975&BBOX=-296598.1830774266%2C5073374.667157855%2C1377331.2461184468%2C5668916.062328799) to one of the tiles:

https://www.gisimmorisknaturgefahren.de/erdbeben_tile?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=true&CRS=EPSG%3A25832&STYLES=&WIDTH=2741&HEIGHT=975&BBOX=-296598.1830774266%2C5073374.667157855%2C1377331.2461184468%2C5668916.062328799

The main problem I have got is the missing layers-information ... addWMSTiles() seems to need it, but the link gives me no clue.

The tiles can be seen at work at this webpage: 
https://www.gisimmorisknaturgefahren.de/immorisk.html

Comment: Help other users help you by explaining in what way the above code does not work.  What did you expect to happen, what actually happens?  How are you running your code?

Comment: are you sure about the URL?? It doesn't look like a valid url for a WMST service

Comment: I tried to extract the information from this link/image:  https://www.gisimmorisknaturgefahren.de/erdbeben_tile?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=true&CRS=EPSG%3A25832&STYLES=&WIDTH=2363&HEIGHT=975&BBOX=314567.50670052296%2C5263898.910947534%2C675328.159544461%2C5412784.25974027

Comment: Did you ask this before as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59070188/how-to-add-wms-tiles-via-addwmstiles-when-ther-is-no-layer-info ?